# Prove that these Dirichlet L function are equal to these zeta function products.

Tags: riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

Prove or disprove that:

$$2 L_{2,1}(s)-2 \zeta (s)+\zeta (s)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right) \zeta (s)$$

$$3 L_{3,1}(s)-3 \zeta (s)+\zeta (s)=\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{s-1}}\right) \zeta (s)$$

Where $L_{2,1}(s)$ and $L_{3,1}(s)$ are Dirichlet L functions and $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Mathematica:

```
Limit[2 DirichletL[2, 1, s] - 2*Zeta[s] + Zeta[s], s -> Pi + Sqrt[2] I]
N[%]
Limit[(1 - 1/2^(s - 1)) Zeta[s], s -> Pi + Sqrt[2] I]
N[%]

Limit[3 DirichletL[3, 1, s] - 3*Zeta[s] + Zeta[s], s -> Pi + Sqrt[2] I]
N[%]
Limit[(1 - 1/3^(s - 1)) Zeta[s], s -> Pi + Sqrt[2] I]
N[%]
```

Comment: $L_{a,b}(s)$ is not a very standard notation. What is the Dirichlet character associated to $L_{3,1}(s)$, for instance? The principal character $\pmod{3}$?

Comment: Yes you are right now when I think about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that $L_{p,1}(s)$ is the Dirichlet $L$-function associated with the principal character $\pmod{p}$.

About the first identity:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)\zeta(s) &=& -\zeta(s)+2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right)\zeta(s)=-\zeta(s)+2\prod_{p\neq 2}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\\&=&-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}+2\!\!\!\!\sum_{n\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!\!2}}\frac{1}{n^s}=-\zeta(s)+L_{2,1}(s).\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
In a similar way,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{s-1}}\right)\zeta(s)=-2\zeta(s)+3\prod_{p\neq 3}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}=-2\zeta(s)+L_{3,1}(s),\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
so everything follows from the Euler product for the $\zeta$ function.